# GPU or power supply is not working well

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, power, gpu

My story: my PC freezes daily and a weird smell comes from the power supply. 
I replaced the power supply. The PC worked well for about 1 hour then shutdown automatically and I couldn't restart it.

The power supply is dead, the motherboard led won't light up. I tried to start power supply without pc(green wired + black wire) but nothing.

Then I put back my old power supply and the PC started, after 1 hour it shutdown again and I can't start it.  When I remove the GPU the PC starts with black screen obviously, but not when starting with the GPU. Now the motherboard led lights up.

Where is the problem ? Any solution? why new power supply dead?  Thanks for the answers.:(

Comment: do you have a power supply tester like [this](http://www.amazon.com/Innoo-Power-Supply-Tester-Display/dp/B008HOSNUU/ref=sr_1_13?ie=UTF8&qid=1356532383&sr=8-13&keywords=power+supply+tester)? It might be worth the $20 in this case

Comment: Well, too many reasons. A surge, a fault with PSU, some spilled a drink in it, dust, a short, faulty cable, fuse blew.... To many reasons as to why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've suffered from this problem before. It was a **power** issue, not a power supply issue. In my case, my coaxial cable internet connection needed to an amplifier to work properly (as opposed to plugging it directly into the modem, an amp was placed between the modem and and the wall jack). At the time I was living in a somewhat rural part of America. This amplification, once installed, later fried any power supply I had put into my desktop PC. And yes, the room would fill with a  slight burnt smell before the power supply later died. You are getting voltage that is too high from either the wall outlet or perhaps the Ethernet jack. Rural areas and areas with poor electric work are prone to this.

As for removing the GPU... The GPU, especially ones designed for gaming, require a lot of power. By removing that, you are putting less stress on the PSU. So the issue may have nothing to with the GPU directly. My guess is that is only delaying the problem as your most likely damaged PSU will eventually completely die.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, if not the gpu is my problem, then what parts of my pc kill a new power supply?

Comment: I don't think the problem is with any part of your computer. I think it is coming from outside of your computer (wall outlet or Ethernet).